# Teste de integração com Jest - API nodejs + Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, tdd, jest

Gostaria de uma ajuda nos meus testes, pois estou fazendo algo errado pois tem hora que o meu teste passa e logo em seguida não passa mais. Segue abaixo alguns os dois testes que eu tenho da minha aplicação de estudo.

```js
const request = require('supertest');

const { Category } = require('../../src/models/category');

describe('/categories', () => {
  let server;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    server = require('../../index');
    const categories = [{ name: 'Electronics' }, { name: 'Books' }];

    await Category.deleteMany({});
    await Category.insertMany(categories);
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await Category.deleteMany({});
  });

  describe('GET /', () => {
    it('should return all categories', async () => {
      const response = await request(server).get('/categories');
      expect(response.status).toBe(200);
      expect(response.body.length).toBe(2);
    });
  });

  describe('POST /', () => {
    it('should register a new category', async () => {
      const category = { name: 'Video Game' };

      const response = await request(server)
        .post('/categories')
        .send(category);

      expect(response.status).toBe(201);
      expect(response.body).toHaveProperty('name', category.name);
    });
  });
});
```

[Teste de integração de categorias - Gist](https://gist.github.com/JAAFSANTOS/2a7398d96f343a50565fbe759f4ffbed)

```js
const request = require('supertest');

const { Product } = require('../../src/models/product');
const { Category } = require('../../src/models/category');

describe('/products', () => {
  let server;
  const defaultCategoryId = '56cb91bdc3464f14678934ca';

  const cleanDatabase = async () => {
    await Category.deleteMany({});
    await Product.deleteMany({});
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    server = require('../../index');
    await cleanDatabase();

    let category = new Category({ name: 'Movie', _id: defaultCategoryId });
    category = await category.save();

    const product = {
      name: 'Star Wars',
      description: 'Star Wars: The Last Jedi',
      category: {
        _id: category._id,
        name: category.name,
      },
      price: 14.99,
    };
    await Product.insertMany([product]);
  });

  afterEach(async () => await cleanDatabase());

  describe('GET /', () => {
    it('should return all products', async () => {
      const response = await request(server).get('/products');

      expect(response.status).toBe(200);
      expect(response.body.length).toBe(1);
    });
  });

  describe('POST /', () => {
    it('should register a new product', async () => {
      const product = {
        name: 'Solo',
        description: 'A Star Wars story',
        categoryId: defaultCategoryId,
        price: 17.75,
      };

      const response = await request(server)
        .post('/products')
        .send(product);

      expect(response.status).toBe(201);
      expect(response.body).toHaveProperty('name', product.name);
    });
  });
});
```

[Teste de integração de produtos - Gist](https://gist.github.com/JAAFSANTOS/c6d5613ee8ef4b593e23ca8a3e681b7a)

[image: Teste passando]

*Teste passando*

[image: Teste falhando]

*Teste falhando **(Sem mudar nada na implementação apenas rodando novamente)***

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço muito.

[Repositório Github](https://github.com/JAAFSANTOS/shop-test-jest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode estar dando conflito nos teste, pois eles não rodam em sequência por padrão, logo, quando tu cria as instâncias no banco, pode estar havendo duplicidade. Pra isto, no teu package.json, passa um parâmetro para o script de test:
    `"test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --verbose --forceExit --runInBand"`